# gitosis vs gitolite?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitolite

I am looking for installing a git server to share projects with my team. I don't want to create a user account on the server with SSH access for each developer that needs a git access.
It seems there is two concurrent solutions that cover this issue : gitosis & gitolite.

I could not find any comparison between both solutions. What are the main differences between them? Are there other similar solution?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

> I am looking for installing a git server to share projects with my team.

### You can *just* use git.

To have a git server the only thing you need on the remote server is git. If you don't require fine-grained permissions (sharing with only your team suggests that's a possibility) or any extra features, you don't need gitolite, or similar.

### The no-install solution

If git is available on the remote server, you can do what you're asking right now, without doing anything

```
ssh [user@]server
cd repos/are/here/
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
```

Locally:

```
cd projects/are/here/project
git remote add origin [user@]server:repos/are/here/project.git
git push -u origin master
```

### Setting up a git server is easy.

If you want to do things with a dedicated git user, the docs for [setting up a git server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) are short - because it really is quite easy to do.

In summary:

- Install git
- Create a user named git
- Add your and your team's public keys to the git user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file
- Change the git user's shell to be `git-shell`
- Create repos on the server
- start git pull/pushing to git@yourserver.com

The *only* difference between using a dedicated git user and not, is that if you setup the git user to use `git-shell` it won't allow itself to do anything else. In terms of acting as a git server though, it's identical to the no-install solution

Comment: After installing the beast that is GitLab+Gitolite, if you don't need fine control over projects etc, this is way to go.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Actually when I said that I did not want to create user accounts for each, I should have also mentioned that I don't want my git users to have access to the server shell through ssh. With your solution I think they would have access to the shell through the "git" user, right?

Comment: For the no-install solution, I had to use `git push origin master` instead of just `git push`.

Comment: @wsams: `git push -u origin master` and you can use `git push` after it. I prefer gito* because in my opinion nobody accessing a repo should have to care about the absolute path it has on the remote system.

Comment: @ThiefMaster taking a wild guess at what you mean, if you put repos in `/home/git/` the url to access a project is `git@server:project.git`.

Comment: @wsams read this part of the answer "Change the git user's shell to be git-shell".

Comment: This is a normal user - I wouldn't want to use `git-shell` @fabspro.

Answer (score 142):

The main difference is that gitosis is now obsolete, and not actively maintained anymore.

Gitolite is much [more feature complete](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/morefeatures_.html), and just released its [third version](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/why.html).

Its most interesting feature is the **[Virtual Reference (VREF for short)](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html)** which allows you to declare as many [update hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) as you want, which allows you to restrict a push by:

- **dir/file name**:
  Say you don't want junior developers pushing changes to the Makefile, because it's quite complex:
  `-   VREF/NAME/Makefile          =   @junior-devs`
- **number of new files**:
  Say you don't want junior developers pushing more than 9 files per commit, because you want them to make *small* commits:
  `-   VREF/COUNT/9/NEWFILES           =   @junior-devs`
- **advanced filetype detection**:
  Sometimes a file has a standard extension (that cannot be 'gitignore'd), but it is actually automatically generated. Here's one way to catch it:
  `-   VREF/FILETYPE/AUTOGENERATED     =   @all`
  See [`src/VREF/FILETETYPE`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/FILETYPE#L28) to see the detection mechanism.
- **checking author email**:
  Some people want to ensure that "you can only push your own commits".
  `-   VREF/EMAIL-CHECK     =   @all`
  See [`src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK).
- **voting on commits**:
  A basic implementation of voting on a commit is surprisingly easy:
  `-   VREF/EMAIL-CHECK     =   @all`.
  `# 2 votes required to push master, but trusted devs don't have this restriction`
  `# RW+ VREF/VOTES/2/master = @trusted-devs`
  `# - VREF/VOTES/2/master = @devs`
  See [`src/VREF/VOTES`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/VOTES) for the implementation.
- and so on...

Comment: I've been using Gitolite for over 3 years now. Never had any problems with it. I our production and staging servers have read-only access to the repos the need. And its an easy job to then share a project with other Development teams. Also it's easy to setup if you know unix and git already :)

Comment: Gitolite documentation includes comparisons to alternatives: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#alt

Answer (score 15):

Just a sidenote. You can also use **Gerrit** for your needs:

[Gerrit Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)

First it seems that Gerrit is used for Code review, but you can actually use it also for managing users and give them good defined permissions. You can **bypass** code-review(trough **access controls**) and use it just for managing projects and ssh-keys. Gerrit has a really strong access control mechanism:

[Gerrit Access Controls](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4/access-control.html)

You can restrict to push for any branches, tags or anything you can imagine that is defined in the access controls document.

Answer (score 8):

For an even quicker and dirtier solution, just use [git daemon](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) and go peer-to-peer. [Here's an article](http://geekaholic.github.io/blog/2012/05/14/git-on-p2p-development/) about doing just that.

Edit: I recognize this doesn't strictly answer the OP's question. I put this here mainly for those, like me, who come across this while looking for a down and dirty way to share code until an enterprise github account gets set up.

Answer (score 2):

I have been messing around for a while to get a git server working with LDAP access, fine grained access control etc... Found a revelation: Use [Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/):

- git repositories
- fine grained access (afaik gitlab uses gitolite under the hood)

if you want the quick and fast installation method: use the [bitnami installer](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab)

Comment: Yes, but GitLab (with gitlab-shell) lost all the VREF hooks that you could easily setup with Gitolite. And a lot of people would like them back: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/14 and https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/pull/85