# Git - Branch status (frozen, inactive, etc.)

Tags: git

Is there a way so set a branch as `inactive` or `frozen` ? Indeed, I don't want to delete my branch as I'm likely to work on it in the future but the branch is currently frozen.

I know i can change the name of the branch to a pattern like `frozen/my-branch` but I'd like to know whether a native way to achieve this already exists in git.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Freezing a Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996248/freezing-a-git-branch)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way AFAIK. A solution I like most is to make a tag to the head of the branch. If I have a branch `foo` which will not work for some time, I usually do:

```
git tag TAG-foo foo
git branch -D foo
```

Now it does not clutter the `git branch` output anymore and I can get it back whenever I want.

**EDIT**: I answered from memory but got curious about it and searched on Google. I found this [interesting extension](https://github.com/smoynes/git-freeze) but I have never used int so I can't endorse it.

Comment: +1 for the 'interesting extension' https://github.com/smoynes/git-freeze/blob/master/bin/git-freeze  I had been looking at trying to create a special (empty) 'dead-branch' into which they were merged, but this looks more interesting / useful / off-the-shelf. (The problem was to get the tree sha1 on of the last commit to as to avoid a checkout-merge and directly construct the dead-branch commit)

Comment: It's been a million years since you posted this solution; is it still what you use or have you found something better?  I'm a heavy user of feature-branches as a developer, but my boss is slow to check and merge my work.  I have a workaround, but want a way to "deprecate" or "inactivate" the old branches (in particular, on the remote side).

Comment: Hey! I still use branch-to-tag approach. There may be other solutions these days, but I'll be honest, I didn't discover any so far.

Comment: Sounded awesome, so I applied it. Shortly after, panicked whether commits on that branch are lost when the branch is deleted...they are not. You can delete a branch with a tag, but the tagged commit and the commits prior to it remain and can be cloned/checked out. The tag acts almost like a branch, just another pointer.