# How to make a branch read-only in git/stash

Tags: git

I have a release branch "R1", to which my feature branches would get merged once they are developed and tested successfully.

So when "R1" is released, i want to make the branch "R1" Read-only, so that no more merges or commits are possible on it.

I just dont want to tag it and keep the tag, i want to stop any changes on that branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git branch permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248246/git-branch-permissions/13248418#13248418)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996248/freezing-a-git-branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to restrict Git branch access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781240/a-way-to-restrict-git-branch-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially *freeze* a branch using the [Commit Policy Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.bitbucket.plugin.commitpolicy/server/overview):

1. Create a new commit policy
2. Reduce its scope to your branch (or branches using a name pattern)
3. Only allow the filenames matching the glob "!({*})" (i.e. do not allow any files added/deleted/modified)