# What is a "stale" git branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

A "Stale" git branch is a term I've heard a lot. I know it has something to do with branches which are regarded as less useful or useless, but cannot find an exact definition. What is a "stale" git branch?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The oldest reference to "stale" is found in [commit e194cd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e194cd1e0e08611462eb9c5a731a7a3d797f9252) (Jan. 2007, Git 1.5.0), which detected "**stale tracking branches in remote**": when tracking a branch which was removed by the remote system.
Hence [`git remote prune`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/859607dfe04260d55f5901974fdd660aebc427fa).

That is the main definition for stale branch: a [**remote tracking branch**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309) (a *local* reference of a remote repo branch) which **no longer tracks anything** (because the actual branch on the remote repo is gone).

`git remote show` is able to list those.

---

Incidentally, you have two other definitions of "stale" in the Git system:

- Another reference to "stale" involves [`git reflog --stale-fix`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) in [commit 1389d9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1389d9ddaa68a4cbf5018d88f971b9bbb7aaa3c9) (Git 1.5.0), for tracking "**broken commit**": a commit that is not reachable from any of the refs and there is a missing object among the commit, tree, or blob objects reachable from it that is not reachable from any of the
  refs.
  That helps fixing situation after running non reflog-aware [`git prune`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) from an older git in the presence of reflogs.
- [Commit 740fdd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/740fdd27f0888d5c80ef6a550734bdc53febd2df) (March 2008, Git 1.5.5) also introduces "stale" for **symbolic refs**, when the ref they point to no longer exists.

---

As mentioned by @SteelToe: 
The definition of a stale branch, as per [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/), is a branch that has not had any commits in the previous 3 months.
This generally indicates an old/unmaintained/not current branch.

Comment: I saw this when I was pushing to a brand-new remote origin, because it didn't have any of my branches on it (obviously).

Comment: "a remote tracking branch" <-- when you say this, it makes me think that you're talking about a branch that exists in the remote repo, but what you mean is a remote branch that you've _locally_ tracked before, but "the actual branch on the remote repo is gone" right ?

Comment: @Honey (a few months late) Yes, that is the idea. I have updated the answer to add a link which illustrates what a remote tracking branch is.

Answer (score 106):

The definition of a stale branch, as per GitHub documentation, is a branch that has not had any commits in the previous 3 months.

This generally indicates an old/unmaintained/not current branch.

For more information see https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/

Answer (score 22):

That's because there is no "exact definition".  "Stale git branch", "stale data", "stale configuration options" -- none of these have an *exact* definition, but they all refer to things that are considered old/unmaintained/not current/possibly broken.

So a "stale git branch" is generally a branch of the repository that hasn't been touched in a long time.  Maybe it's broken, maybe not; it's certainly not current w/r/t to the active development branch, and nobody has looked at it for a while.

Comment: On github, branches not updated in the last 3 months are considered stale : https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository

Answer (score 11):

**Stale branch** is a branch without activity after some time. In Github it's stale after 3 months of inactivity.

Reasons, why projects have stale branches: unreleased features, prototype, alternative solution, incomplete, incompatible.

[read more](https://medium.com/@vbabak/how-to-deal-with-stale-branches-on-the-github-b49727480872)