# git fetch to different local remote refspec

Tags: git

I have only master branch on my remote origin.

Then I did:

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master2
```

as a result I got:

```
* [new branch]      master     -> origin/master2
```

which seems all right.

It is shown as remote tracking branch with the master:

```
bash$ git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
origin/master2
```

but master2 is shown as :

```
bash$ git remote show origin
  Remote branches:
master                      tracked
refs/remotes/origin/master2 stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
```

I. My first question is why master2 is shown as stale? I was able to fetch to it (and create it as my local remote tracking one) and I would expect that it will be mapped to remote origin/master?

II. Second question is why I have to do:

```
bash$ git branch -r -d origin/master2
```

to delete it and got error when trying to do it by giving full refspec:

```
bash$ git branch -r -d refs/remotes/origin/master2
error: remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/origin/master2' not found.
```

I've checked man of git-branch and found there nothing special about branch name:

```
<branchname>
       The name of the branch to create or delete. The new branch name
       must pass all checks defined by git-check-ref-format(1). Some of
       these checks may restrict the characters allowed in a branch name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my previous answer "[What is a “stale” git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29117032/6309)": you are creating a local `master` branch tracking a remote branch named `master2`.
But `master2` does not exist in the `origin` repo.
Hence the stale attribute.

The fetch does not fetch any commit from the remote non-existing branch `master2`, but does create a local `master` branch tracking `origin/master2`, which means the next `git push` would push (and create) `origin/master2`.

As I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715674/6309), a simple `git fetch origin -p --progress` would remove `origin/master2`.

As mentioned by [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2968398/user1337) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983314/git-fetch-to-different-local-remote-refspec/47983375?noredirect=1#comment82936579_47983375), the chapter "**[Git Internals - The Refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)**" does include:

> If you want to do a one-time only fetch, you can specify the specific refspec on the command line, too.
>   To pull the `master` branch on the remote down to `origin/mymaster` locally, you can run:

```
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. As I understand after first push master2 will be created on remote, after that my local refs/remotes/origin/master2 will loose 'stale' status but both origin/master2 and remotes/origin/master2 will be empty ones?

Comment: @user1337 yes, after a first push, `master2` will lose the 'stale' status. But it won't be empty: it will have at least one commit from `master`.

Comment: I found it in: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec where you can find: If you want to do a one-time only fetch, you can specify the specific refspec on the command line, too. To pull the master branch on the remote down to origin/mymaster locally, you can run:

$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster

Comment: @user1337 Good catch: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.