# Cloning through SSH makes the server think that GIT’s home directory is the root of the filesystem?

Tags: git

I have set up a simple server with a single git account to which I connect using SSH.
I try to clone a repository located in its home directory (/srv/git) with `git clone ssh://git@server:port/repository`. It won’t work unless I prepend `~/` to the repository name.
If I don’t prepend it, it will work only if the repository is located at the root of the filesystem.

Somehow, git is not realizing its own user directory. How can I change this “odd” behaviour so it works as expected? (at least for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide an absolute path or a path using the `~` to indicate the home directory. Quoting from [`git-clone(1)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> The ssh and git protocols additionally support ~username expansion:
>
> - `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `git://host.xz[:port]/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `[user@]host.xz:/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/`

An alternate solution would be using something such as [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). Then you will be able to use repository URLs such as `sshuser@host:reponame`

Comment: Exactly the enlightenment I was looking for. Thanks for que quick reply.

Comment: Could we all agree to let gitosis go now? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358)