# gitolite setup reverted changes

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm experiencing a weird problem, which I think might be a bug.

I pushed a change in the configuration to the Git server. This included a new repository, so after pushing I logged on to the server to create and initialize the repo (as a copy of the main product repo teamer.git):

```
rwel@ve-git:/home/git/repositories/teamer$ sudo su git
git@ve-git:~/repositories/teamer$ git clone --bare ../teamer.git analytics.git
git@ve-git:~/repositories/teamer$ gitolite setup
```

The weird thing is, running "gitolite setup" appears to have reverted my changes! In the repository, a new commit has appeared with exactly the previous state of the configuration:

[image: GitX screen shot]
What has happened here and how can I fix it? If you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** I got some errors after pushing the new config, might have something to do with it:

```
gitolite-admin rwel$ git push origin
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.07 KiB, done.
Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: *** hooks.mailinglist is not set so no email will be sent
remote: *** for refs/heads/master update 85dd4c5e7592fadbdb0d445a245a8763d6e2042b->1063acec3b106b348fadac655d154a78ea15ead5
remote: FATAL: no files/dirs called 'hooks' or 'logs' are allowed
```

Comment: Why would you manually create a bare repo on the Gitolite server side? Declaring it in the `gitolite.conf` file of the `gitolite-admin` repo (and pushing that one) is enough to triggering the new repo creation.

Comment: Note: by looking at the picture, you are indeed pushing gitolite-admin, but I still don't see why you would have to create a bare repo your self on the Gitolite server.

Comment: @VonC: I know, but for some reason this did not happen. I did get some errors after the push (I'll add them to the post), maybe this had something to do with it. But I needed to create the repo manually anyway, as I need it to be a clone of another repo instead of a fresh one.

Comment: "hooks.mailinglist is not set"? Do you have some hook like a git-commit-notice (http://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-gambas/git-commit-notice) in place for all repos? Gitolite doesn't install that, and if you need it, you would declare it as a VREF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358), not a classic hook.

Comment: Yes, I've added a `post-receive` hook in `hooks/common`, that sends out notifications when one of my fellow developers pushes a new commit to his/her repo (so I know I need to evaluate the code and merge it in the develop branch). Is this not right? Strange, cause it was working perfectly..

Comment: With gitolite V3, you would declare any post-receive hook as a VREF. It could have side-effect with the `gitolite setup` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I had my (common) hooks placed in the root directory of the Gitolite admin repository (`[gitolite-admin.git]/hooks/common`). Git does not like this, hence the error:

```
remote: FATAL: no files/dirs called 'hooks' or 'logs' are allowed
```

Probably because of this, my Gitolite install got messed up, with the setup script appearantly trying to revert the failed commit.

### The fix

1. First, I had to clean up the mess in the `gitolite-admin.git` repo by cloning it on the server, resetting it to `HEAD^` and force-pushing that back to the repo (as explained [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#bypass)).

   ```
   git@ve-git:~/temp$ git reset --hard HEAD^
   git@ve-git:~/temp$ gitolite push origin -f
   ```
2. To fix the fatal error, I simply moved the hooks to a subdirectory, [as advised in the documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/cust.html#localcode) (in a branch based on the reset `master` from step 1):

   ```
   $ git checkout -b hooksfix origin/master
   $ mkdir extra
   $ mv hooks extra
   $ git add --all
   $ git commit -m "moved hooks directory to prevent errors"
   $ git push origin hooksfix:master
   ```

   To make this work, I also had to add a line to the `.gitolite.rc` file on the Git server:

   ```
   LOCAL_CODE                  => "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/extra",
   ```
3. After pushing this, the fatal error was gone. I then proceeded to rebase my initial change on the fixed `master`, and could now also push that with no problems.

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git rebase origin/master
   $ git push origin
   ```

Comment: My gitolite installation script takes advantage of the `LOCAL_CODE` variable to isolate any hook/VREF in its own separate directory: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh