# How can I enable anonymous read access (pull) but authenticated write access (push) to a git repository over http?

Tags: git, apache, version-control

I want to have git repository available via "smart" **HTTP** to which only I can push, but which anybody (or anybody with account) can clone / fetch from.

In the [git-http-backend(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) manpage one can find the following example configuration for Apache web server:

> Ensure mod_cgi, mod_alias, and mod_env are enabled, set GIT_PROJECT_ROOT (or DocumentRoot) appropriately, and create a ScriptAlias to the CGI:
>
> ```
> SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
> SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
> ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
> ```
>
> To enable anonymous read access but authenticated write access, require authorization with a LocationMatch directive:
>
> ```
> <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
>         AuthType Basic
>         AuthName "Git Access"
>         Require group committers
>         #...
> </LocationMatch>
> ```

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work.  I can fetch / clone repository without any problems, without requiring authenthication, but pushing fails:

```
$ git push origin master
error: Cannot access URL http://localhost/git/test.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Examining `error.log` of Apache web server doesn't help:

```
[...] Service not enabled: 'receive-pack'
[...] Request not supported: '/var/www/git/test.git/'
```

The `access.log` tells us that `git push` first uses GET method on `/git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack` query-based URL, which is not covered by LocationMatch directive:

```
[...] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 304 "-" "git/1.7.10.4"
[...] "GET /git/test.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 267 "-" "git/1.7.10.4"
[...] "GET /git/test.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 337 "-" "git/1.7.10.4"
[...] "PROPFIND /git/test.git/ HTTP/1.1" 404 250 "-" "git/1.7.10.4"
```

(the following lines are about fallback to "dumb" WebDAV based HTTP push - is it possible to disable this fallback?).

---

For now I use the following workaround: I require valid user for both fetch and push (using modified configuration from "authentication for both reads and writes" example in [git-http-backend(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) manpage), and restrict push to single user via `pre-receive` [hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) by examining `REMOTE_USER` environment variable.

Comment: You can write (or use) a hook that checks credentials (environment variables) and reject unwanted pushes. You can also limit things per-ref this way (E.g. allow pushes to "devel", but only certain users to "master")

Comment: @Vi.: I know, that is what I do in my _"fallback"_ solution... but my fallback solution requires `valid-user`, so it is not really anonymous read (fetch).

Comment: @JakubNarębski oh... my solution also requires `valid-user`, as currently configured. You could set `REMOTE_USER` to a dummy value in your anonymous access section though. Since `@all` would be set inthe gitolite config, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Why not try making the LocationMatch cover _also_ what you see is requested? For example with `LocationMatch "^/git/.*git-receive-pack$"` (without the last slash). It has all the looks of a simple bug (missing update?) in the documentation.

Comment: The suggested change will (obviously?) not work as is, but [this discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/204286) confirms the problem and provides likely working solutions.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski: `LocationMatch` does matching only on the path_info part of URL and does not take into account the query part, which is important here.

Comment: @JakubNarębski: yes, I know it now (from the linked thread). There are other configuration changes suggested there, that seem to work for the posters.

Answer (score 1):

One not so complex alternative is to use [**gitolite**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358) in addition of your Apache-git setup.
You can plug gitolite to Apache easily enough (no ssh config required).

See as an example: [httpd.conf](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L132), combined with this local [gitolite installation script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh).

You can then easily declare Apache logins for Write access, and `@all` for read access.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your repo `.git/config` file with the following value:

```
[http]
    receivepack = true
```

Comment: You can improve you answer by formatting it better.