# GitLab PHP Website Deployment

Tags: git, deployment, hook, gitlab

I've setup [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com) and am using it to host my Git repositories. Now what I'm trying to do is setup a `post-receive` hook so that I can develop in a folder called `site_dev` then push my changes so they're automatically pulled into the `site` folder.

All morning I've been trying to get this hook to work however I've not had any luck executing any commands with GitLab running on Ubuntu Server, I know that the `resque` service is running and my workers are active.

Currently I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIVE="/var/www/teamnet"
# read oldrev newrev refname
# if [ $refname = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
  echo "===== DEPLOYING TO LIVE SITE ====="
  cd $LIVE || exit
  unset GIT_DIR
  git pull
  echo "===== DONE ====="
# fi
```

Attempting to pull my changes.

I'm not sure whether I've done something wrong here... All folders are in the same location `/var/www/` on the same server. And yes, I have ran `chmod +x` on the hook.

Yes, I've ran `git init --bare` for the *live* folder and set the origin to the Git repository. I'm a little confused however as to where this hook should live, the live/dev folder?

Comment: Why your "read" is in a comment?

Comment: Well when I was looking at other example hooks, they didn't have it at all. I've tried with and without comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which is used by [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/), you must declare your post-receive hook [as VREF](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html) (that I [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)).

That supposes that your `.gitolite.rc` contains a `LOCAL_CODE` variable (see [this script](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh#L38-L44)) in order to store your VREFs in a directory of your choice.

Then you can associate that VREF (which is just an hook executable) to one or many repo in the `gitolite.conf` of the `gitolite-admin` repo. (manually, since there is no interface for that through GitLab)

Comment: Is there a walkthrough for doing this with regards to GitLab? :)

Comment: @James not that I know of: I clone myself the gitolite-admin repo on the gitlab server (anywhere), make my modif and push back.

Comment: Okay, but I'm still none-the-wiser as to how I set this hook up? Does it go on the dev repository or the live one, or neither and instead the server?

Comment: Right, now I've managed to find `.gitolite.rc` I don't see the `LOCAL_CODE` variable, so if I follow your link and add it in, where do I go from there?

Comment: That kind of Vref is set on the device repo, managed by gitolite & gitlab. Its action is to switch to the live repo and pull.

Comment: So I'd go into the `*.git` repo and add the action there?

Comment: Is it safe to delete the `post-receive` hook that's already been created and symlinked?

Comment: Wahey! Now I just need to fix the permissions as I'm getting "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" which I assume is because the `git` user is trying to pull?

Comment: If it is one you have created, yes.

Comment: Yes, you need to be sure the user git is authorized to pull.

Comment: How do I do this? I can't login as the git user to get the ssh key?

Comment: Yet git becomes a user like any other, which must be granted access to the project in order to pull.