# Block and/or Identify Fake author name/email in GIT

Tags: git, security, commit, gitolite, spoofing

I want to block fake users in `git commit`. That means one user must not be able to change his/her email with someone else. I use gitolite. How can I implement this feature? As I have users' public keys, can I bind their email/name to that public key?

Answer (score 2):

> As I have users' public key, can I bind email/name with that public key?

Not natively: Gitolite only works with the user id (as extracted from the http or ssh session and set in a variable `GL_USER`)

So you need to have that information elsewhere.

What I use is the public keys which are given by the users and stored in the `gitolite/keys` dir of the `gitolite-admin` repo.

A public ssh key is composed of 3 parts:

```
 ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx WhateverYouWant
```

The last part, after the public key, is a string which can represent what you want.

I demand from the user a key with their email address in it (at the end).
I then setup a [`VREF` (an update hook in gitolite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358) for all repo, which will validate the `user.email` seen in the commits with the email extracted from the `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
That file is managed by gitolite, and contains both the `user.name` and its email (because of the way I expect the users to give me their public key)

```
 command=="..../gitolite-shell user-id" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx WhateverYouWant
```

If any of the email doesn't match the right user name, the VREF hook will reject the push.

---

My own [VREF `CHECKID`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/passenger/gitolite/VREF/CHECKID.tpl) (for a slightly different) purpose, is declare in the `gitolite.conf` as:

```
repo    @all
  RW+                            = gitoliteadm
  -     VREF/CHECKID             = @all
```

Comment: Thank you for let me know about VREF. It is really useful, but somehow I failed to make it work with user.email I have also checked it's document http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/vref.html#virtual_refs_checking_author_email_
can you please help me a bit more

Comment: I have user 
`- VREF/EMAIL-CHECK = @all` 
against one repository
even also use
`repo @all
  - VREF/EMAIL-CHECK = @all`
None of those work

Comment: @Sadi I have edited my answer with an example of a VREF config.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a hook that takes a slightly different approach than the previous answer. You put in an EMAILDOMAIN at the top, and it makes sure that the email address on the commit log equals [the committing user's SSH key file name]@[EMAILDOMAIN].

I tossed this into gitolite-admin/common-hooks so it runs server side on pushes.

```
#!/bin/bash

EMAILDOMAIN="company.com"

if [[ $2 = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ]] || [[ $3 = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ]]
then
  exit 0
fi

# get name and email from git log
EMAILCMD="git log --format="%ce" $3 -1"
EMAIL=$($EMAILCMD)  
NAMECMD="git log --format="%cn" $3 -1"
NAME=$($NAMECMD)

# environment variable for the gitolite user (the SSH key)
# echo $GL_USER

# compare email with gitolite user
EXPEMAIL="$GL_USER@$EMAILDOMAIN"
if [ "{$EXPEMAIL,,}" != "{$EMAIL,,}" ]
then
  echo "You're committing with the SSH key for '$GL_USER'. That key belongs to $EXPEMAIL."
  echo "  (You've configured your email as $EMAIL)"
  exit 1
fi

# TODO: maybe, if we ever bother installing mail on this box, send an email to some admins if someone is trying to key share

# check the name...
IFS=' ' read -ra NAMEPARTS <<< "${NAME,,}"
PARTCOUNT=0
for PART in "${NAMEPARTS[@]}"
do
  PARTCOUNT=$((PARTCOUNT+1))
done

# make sure it's a full name
if (( "$PARTCOUNT" < 2 ))
then
  echo "You should put in your full name, $NAME."
  echo "If you've really only got one name (like Sting or Madonna), email an admin and we can make an exception for you."
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Interesting approach, different from my answer. +1