# Gitlab committer's email does "X" does not follow the pattern "Y", but git email config is "X"

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-config

I am trying to push to a repo and unable to do so because of a pre-receive hook which does not allow me to push because my email is not of a certain type.

I am unable to find where my commiter's email is set to the incorrect email. On Gitlab, my profile contains the correct email.

From the terminal, I have reset the email to the correct email  with `$git config user.email` `alisonz@xxxxxx.com` and confirmed that the email is correct through `$git config user.email`.

Does anyone have any idea on where to start to find where this incorrect email is set? I have checked all the config files I'm aware of and they all contain the correct email.

Thanks for any tips or suggestions on where to start debugging this.

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message when you try to push, as well as the output of `git log`?

Comment: Can you list all the config files you're aware of? Does the error message tell you what the incorrect email address is? Does the incorrect email address appear in an environment variable?

Comment: can you please share the exact error ?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28425670/5320906), answers suggest that this is a server-side issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. After trying different solutions, at the end I re-cloned the project from gitlab and it worked!