# git object folder permission

Tags: git, file-permissions, trac

I am trying to hook the trac with git, and most are fine, except for SOME repositories, I could not get the revision information out of git.

After I have done the following, the revision is correctly collected by Trac

```
chmod -R 777 <git-repo>/objects/
```

(I know 777 is very dangerous, it's just for diagnose purpose)

however, for those new commits, the committed items are still of 0700 permission.

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 10:49 80
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 10:49 0a
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 11:01 04
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 11:01 a6
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 11:01 61
drwxrwxrwx 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 11:01 2f
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 12:13 da
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 12:13 a3
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 12:13 8c
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 12:13 26
```

But the strangest part is, for some other git repositories inside the same machine, those new object folders are MOSTLY of 755 permission (which is still fine for Trac).

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2011-07-12 17:22 14
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2011-07-12 17:22 f5
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2011-07-12 17:22 9e
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 aa
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 76
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 c5
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 9c
drwx------ 2 git git 4.0K 2013-02-26 14:12 6a
```

May I know what possibly causes this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Random guess: Maybe a [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) issue?

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. How should I verify or confirm if it's an umask issue or not?

Comment: Are you using gitolite to manage right access to your repos?

Comment: @VonC: yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Walty I have edited my answer to include umask specifics for Gitolite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the user executing track daemon is in the same group than the git user.

Consider this [installation process](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/running-trac-git-hosting-on-a-low-end-vps/):

```
useradd -m -K UMASK=027 git
useradd -m -K UMASK=077 -G git trac
```

Any file created by git with umask 027 would still be readable by trac.

If you are using gitolite, as [mentioned here](http://axcoto.com/blog/article/840), you would need to set `umask` in `.gitolite.rc` to 0027 to allow group have read permission.
See [`Rc.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L319-L328), by default it is 077 instead of 027:

```
# HELP for all the other external programs (the syntactic sugar helpers and
# the various programs/functions in the 8 trigger lists), can be found in
# doc/non-core.mkd (http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/non-core.html) or in
# the corresponding source file itself.

%RC = (
    # if you're using mirroring, you need a hostname. This is *one* simple
    # word, not a full domain name. See documentation if in doubt
    # HOSTNAME => 'darkstar',
    UMASK => 0077,
```

Comment: Thanks, changing of UMASK works! though it's the $REPO_UMASK that I changed. http://www.giocc.com/public-repositories-in-gitolite-with-umasks.html

Comment: @Walty you mean, you are still in gitolite v2? `UMASK` (instead of `REPO_UMASK`) is for gitolite V3, and I recommend the upgrade: its VREFs are a powerful feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358.