# In gitolite, how to reject pushes containing incorrect author info

Tags: git, gitolite

I intend to only accept the commits containning correct author information. like 
`Author: Name<xxxx@xxx.org>`

in gitolite, is there a way to implement it? BTW, I use V2.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with Gitolite V3, it is called [**`VREF`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358), similar to an [EMAIL_CHECK VREF](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/EMAIL-CHECK).

You can also use in g2 (Gitolite V2) "[virtual ref](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/vref.html)" (precursors of g3 VREF), including the [check author email one](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/vref.html#virtual_refs_checking_author_email_): the script is "[`g2/contrib/VREF/gl-VREF-EMAIL_CHECK`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/contrib/VREF/gl-VREF-EMAIL_CHECK)".
You would need to adapt that script to your own email control policy.

For a hook running for all repos on all users, a simpler version would be an `update` hook, but since that version uses the `update` hook already, you will need to *chain* your own `update` hook.
See "[hook chaining](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html#hookchaining)".

> To run your own '`update`' hook, just put it in a file called **`update.secondary`** and install it as a hook.
>   Gitolite's update hook will automatically chain to it, taking care to pass it the same 3 arguments the original update hook received from git.

Comment: Thank you VonC. Hook will run for all repos&usrs, VREF seems to be a good choice.
For my own email control policy, do I need to write a perl script myself to implement the rules or is there an existing script in gitolite V2? If I write it myself, I have to put it in src/ and go with install process, right?

Comment: @Flyakite you would need to write your own script, put it in "`~/.gitolite/hooks/common`" and run "`gl-setup`" again: see http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html

Comment: I put a echo "hello world" in `~/.gitolite/hooks/common/update.secondary`, then `chmod +x` and `gl-setup`. But when I run gl-setup, the code is gone. Do you have some ideas? Thank you:)

Comment: BTW, in gl-pre-git it works. And is it possible to run `git log --format="%ae" -1 $commit` in gl-pre-git or other hooks, what should I do? I tried `$ENV{GL_USER}` in gl-pre-git , but it is different with the info in git log. Many thanks.

Comment: @Flyakite it depends on the version of g2 your are using. [In older version](http://gitolite.googlecode.com/git/doc/2-admin.html?r=f023591183365980d11c1ba352461bea9863746f#_using_hooks), depending on the vay you installed it, you needed to run src/gl-easy-instal instead of `gl-setup`. But the recommended solution is to upgrade to g3. As [I mentioned before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004729/regenerate-authorized-keys-file-in-gitolite/16008436#comment22836017_16008436)n this won't affect your existing repos.

Comment: thank you for the kind help, we are planning for the upgrade. And one more question... How can I get the commit hash that people want to push, from gitolite? I mean, if I use `git log --format="%ae" -1 `, it would be a top commit already in the repo. I intend to get the commit hash the people is going to push...

Comment: @Flyakite my script is another example: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/VREF/CHECKID.tpl, still based on a `git log $oldsha..$newsha`: it will list commits that are *being* pushed and will reject them if some policy is not properly followed.

Comment: cool, thank you very much:) What I did not know is the 3 argument mentioned in the document. It solved now, thank you.