# Regenerate authorized_keys file in gitolite?

Tags: gitolite

Is it possible? My authorized_keys file was wiped, updating gitolite admin rules only appends to file. Is it possible to regenerate the whole file based on gitolite config?

EDIT: found it!

**`gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With gitolite g3 (the version 3.x), a simple:

```
 gitolite setup
```

(executed on the server) is enough.

See [`src/lib/Gitolite/Setup.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Setup.pm):

> Setup gitolite, compile conf, run the POST_COMPILE trigger (see rc file) and
>   propagate hooks.

This one command is easier to remember than `gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE`.

Comment: Problem is I had existing repos and the docs said only run `gitolite setup` with bare repos. I also had custom hooks (redmine), and I didn't need to compile conf, or propogate hooks. Not even sure I have gitolite g3.

Comment: @Zenph this won't affect the bare repo under `~/repositories/`. and it has nothing to do with any clone of those bare repos you might be working with. You have gitolite g3 if you have a [`gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell) in your gitolite sources.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Wasn't sure if setup was going to break my install.