# Can’t connect to gitolite: gl-auth-command not found

Tags: git, gitolite

```
$ git push
sh: /usr/bin/gl-auth-command: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`gl-auth-command` is called from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and is supposed to be in the gitolite repo under `src/`

I’ve pulled the last changes for gitolite repo successfully, but didn’t find any gl-auth-command in it.

```
git@home ~ $ find gitolite -iname "gl-auth*"
git@home ~ $
```

I’ve accomplished migration to v3 a month ago, and it worked back then. The logs in ~/.gitolite/logs/ have last messages about successful repo updates on September, 10th. Then something happened and users can’t log in since then. I have no idea what could it be, moreover, if it looks for `gl-auth-command`, that means that the ssh connection goes normal, so at least, it is not a network problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the gitolite repo under src/

No, it should be in a bin folder after intalling gitolite.
And [`gl-auth-command`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/g2/src/gl-auth-command) seems to indicate an old gitolite 2, which is why you don't find it in the latest gitolite changes.

[Redo a clean installation of the gitolite 3](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html) (and [regenerate your authorized_keys file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008436/6309): `gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE`)

Comment: Nah, `gitolite setup` to update authorized_keys file was all it needed. Thanks. It is really a flaw in documentation because in my case I was cloning gitolite-admin repo back and didn’t run `gitolite setup`.

Comment: @tijagi sure, bu I would still recommend upgrading to gitolite v3. V2 is obsolete.

Comment: I’ve written above, I’ve already migrated month ago. I must probably deleted v2 stuff a week ago and that caused this leftover surprise.

Comment: For some reason I keep getting this message. I mean, after running `gitolite setup` all works fine, but after some days ~/.ssh/authorized_keys again has /usr/bin/gl-auth-command. What does update this file?

Comment: @tijagi maybe another older gitolite installation. Make sure you have only one Gitolite installed.

Comment: Ican say that there’s only one installation: of v3.6.1. Well, will try to look it up in hooks.