# Access control with Git on the server (not gitosis or gitolite)

Tags: git, version-control, access-control

I am trying to set up access control per repo only (with the three permissions no-access, read-only, read/write). I am having an external application control it, which makes syncing admin git repos (such as what gitosis and gitolite provide) not practical.

What would work perfectly is a setup that would allow me to simply call system commands to grant users (ssh keys) access, create repos, and delete repos. for example:

`git-acl grant R user1.pub /path/to/repo.git` - Grants user1 read-only access on the repo
`git-acl grant RE user2.pub /path/to/repo.git` - Grants user2 read/write access on the repo
`git-acl create /path/to/repo2.git` - Creates repo

etc...

Does anyone know of a tool like this?

Comment: This is not a CLI tool, but it may end up being what you resort to using http://gitlab.org/

Answer (score 3):

It seems like basic ssh and file-system access control is the traditional way to accomplish what you are asking.

See https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control

Answer (score 0):

First, you can easily script [gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358) in order to add a user to a repo, by modifying the `gitolite.conf` file and pushing it back.

If you want another system, I only know about [gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell), but it seems quite linked to [gitlabhq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, actually. Part of my beef with gitoite is the fact that everything is stored in a single config file, so either I need to do searches/replaces, or recompile a file (making it painful for larger implementations), in addition I hear that when that file gets big, gitolite itself slows down.

Comment: @jaq yes, but if the file gets that big, I would set up *several* gitolite ;)