# How to set up per-user authorization for Git hosting?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, hosting

I'm wondering how to set up per-user access for git repositories, like Github and Bitbucket do. I've read articles about how to set up Git hosting (basically just allow `git-ssh` access to a git-initialized folder) but I'm not sure how to configure `authorized_keys` on a per-project or per-team basis.

So how would I make an authorization model for Git similar to how popular git hosts do it? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269666/access-control-with-git-on-the-server-not-gitosis-or-gitolite

Comment: That set me on the right track, thank you.