# git shared repo: no correct access rights for extra user

Tags: git, ssh, access-rights

I created a git bare repo on my linux CentOS server:

/home/git/niels.git.

User git and niels are in group git.

I changed /etc/passwd so home dir of niels is git.

ssh as git to niels.git : push and pull fine.

ssh as niels in the same manner gives:

```
fatal: '~/niels.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Clearly the repository exists as I can access it as git.
Here some rights and group info:

```
# ls -al /home/git

total 32
drwxrwx--- 4 git  git   4096 Sep 20 22:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Sep 17 14:39 ..
-rwxr----- 1 git  10009  953 Sep 17 14:19 .bash_history
-rwxr----- 1 git  10009   33 Sep 12 22:46 .bash_logout
-rwxr----- 1 git  10009  176 Sep 12 22:46 .bash_profile
-rwxr----- 1 git  git    124 Sep 12 22:46 .bashrc
drwxrw---- 7 git  git   4096 Sep 17 17:19 niels.git
drwxr----- 2 root 10009 4096 Sep 15 22:40 .ssh

# groups niels

niels : niels git
```

what am I doing wrong?

Oh BTW I tried all kinds of permission like

```
chmod -R 740 /home/git
```

and 766 666
but only with 777 I get the liberating:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

But that can't be the way...

Answer (score 0):

> But that can't be the way...

Yet it is the way: you are not supposed to access repo under `/home/git/` as any other user than 'git'.

ssh opens a secure shell on the remote server (the one which has your **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**), and that shell is used with the user you mention in your ssh url: `git`. That works for accessing `/home/git`.

Changing the `/etc/password` isn't enough to change the *ownership* of that home directory.

You can try a:

```
sudo chmod 744 -R egit /home/git
```

(but then the account `git` will have issue with accessing those same repos)

Comment: "you are not supposed to access repo under /home/git/ as any other user than 'git'."  Ok that I understand.                                                 But how does this combine with the idea of sharing a repo: the essence of Git, to work together on the same project?

Comment: Well I am gonna start from scratch and follow these steps: http://kovshenin.com/2011/howto-remote-shared-git-repository/  thx for your reply VonC

Comment: @user1762879 you don't have to use different users for your remote repo: one is enough.

Comment: @user1762879 but with ssh, I prefer using gitolite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309