# gitosis-init error | Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, git, failed-installation, gitosis

Hy Guys i got some error while setting up gitosis, i think its some kind of not installed python dependencies

here is my output

```
git@ubuntu-server ~ % sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /home/git/cs8898_windows7_21.07.2014.pub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gitosis-init", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gitosis==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'gitosis-init')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 24, in run
    return app.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/app.py", line 38, in main
    self.handle_args(parser, cfg, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 121, in handle_args
    user = ssh_extract_user(pubkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg/gitosis/init.py", line 39, in ssh_extract_user
    raise InsecureSSHKeyUsername(repr(user))
gitosis.init.InsecureSSHKeyUsername: Username contains not allowed characters: '----'
```

Would be nice to get some hints, i will try it my selfe too

Comment: you must have `----` in your username in the .pub file, which is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from [`gitosis/init.py#L34-L39`](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis/blob/2cf64580693d08a22d0d7de077ef5c11208c750a/gitosis/init.py#L34-L39):

```
def ssh_extract_user(pubkey):
    _, user = pubkey.rsplit(None, 1)
    if ssh.isSafeUsername(user):
        return user
    else:
        raise InsecureSSHKeyUsername(repr(user))
```

That means the content of your pubilc key file isn't `abcd...(long_key)...xxxxx= yourName`, but includes at the end `----`.

Sanitizes its content or regenerate your keys.

Comment: Note: consider also upgrading to gitolite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309