# Group multiples GIT repositories in gitosis

Tags: git, gitosis

How is possible to group multiple GIT repositories under some path in Gitosis?
For example Qt5 in gitorious already has same structure (git@gitorious.org:qt/qt5.git) where **qt/** is path for grouping.

Is it possible to make following structure in gitosis ?

1)  git@myserver.com:/project/repo1

2)  git@myserver.com:/project/repo2

```
 [group repo1] 
  members = jdoe 
  writable = project/repo1

 [group repo2] 
  members = jdoe 
  writable = project/repo2
```

Comment: You have a similar notion with wild repo in gitolite: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild.html. But gitosis is too old and obsolete: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309

Comment: gitolite nice especially with regexp syntax in "wild" repos. Thanks for gitolite. So, the only one answer is update to it ?

Comment: Xm, I have found in https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis/blob/master/example.conf reference to repo. with syntax like name/repo I have try it and it works :) so, Actual described above syntax works !

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, I have seen access rules for multiple repos with [gitolite, not gitosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309), and [wild repos](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/wild.html) (user created repos)

> The wildrepos feature allows you to specify access control rules using regular expression patterns, so you can have **many actual repos being served by a single set of rules** in the config file.
>   The regex can also include the word `CREATOR` in it, allowing you to parametrise the name of the user creating the repo.