# Does Git have built-in SSH server?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to setup Git's remote SSH server to access this using SSH, but I haven't found any info how to make this.

Does Git has built-in SSH tools to establish such connection to use this "right out of the box"? Or should I use some third-party one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not have an inbuilt ssh server. Git assumes that

- the `git` client can use the `ssh` binary to initiate an ssh connection
- the `git` server (at least on Unix) can be invoked as a command run from the `ssh` server.

You are probably familiar with the syntax

```
ssh foo.bar baz
```

which runs `baz` on `foo.bar`. The git client uses a similar configuration to run the `ssh` server which in turn runs the server-side git binary (the same binary as the client but run with different flags). Normally you would have a `git` user to do this. You can do this without any programs other than `ssh` and `git` (see first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite)) but you may find installing `gitolite` makes things easier (in essence your git server config is also stored in a `git` repo, so you don't have to do any server side maintenance by logging in).

Comment: Using "client" and "server" may be slightly confusing as it is the same in both ends.

Comment: So does the SSHD daemon need to be up and running (In other words `service ssh start` on ubuntu), or is the ssh binary run on demand on each connection and then exited?  Also for example if I do a push over ssh does the server need to processes to handle the request - one for ssh and one for git - or is it all handled in the same process?

Comment: sshd needs to be available to run processes. In an Ubuntu install, that's nearly always achieved by having a service (and daemon) running, which on a request forks and runs the command requested. If you do a push over ssh, the ssh daemon will fork and run the git binary serve side, which will process the request.

Answer (score 1):

No, I am sorry.
You need to install appropriate ssh tools(like openssh) and configure your server to allow ssh. After that you just [init a bare](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) repository on your server and copy your ssh-key to your server.