# android studio local git

Tags: android, git, android-studio, local

I'm trying to create a local git for my android studio projects.

How I can import project A into Project B like a library using local git without using Github ?

I create the project , enable version control integration and commit it , what is the next step to locally add it into another project ? like i could pull new updates from the library.

Is it possible to add a local project to another project with dependency ?

What is the best way to have a local git ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GIT on local server and local PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896958/using-git-on-local-server-and-local-pc)

Comment: Follow the duplicate link if you want to get started, but realize if your local PC is also the server then you lose some data protection because everything is in the same place.