# GitHub: Restrict Access to specific branch

Tags: github, repository

Is there a way to restrict access to certain branches within a repository? We have production and master branches which sometimes get messed up with rogue pushes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>Not with GitHub in the same repo</del>.
(as opposed to local repos, which can be protected by an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html))

You could have:

- one repo for production and master branch, with only the prod team as collaborators (if there need to be contribution by others, [they can fork that repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974166/6309))
- one repo for other (more "public") branches, for the rest of the team.

---

Update: I still prefer having two repos, but you now (Sept. 2015) can protect a branch on GitHub.
See "[**How to protect “master” in github?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383909/6309)".

Comment: Elegant and easy. Thanks Vonc!

Comment: @VonC any pointer on how a neat setup ensures pull requests and code reviews across the public and production repos?

Comment: @srrvnn mainly putting a gerrit between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25158741/6309