# Send commits for review

Tags: git

We have customer's GIT repo and work as dedicated team. What I need is to perform code-review of our local team before commits are pushed to theirs repo.
I thought about creating local repo for our commits but this is not seemed to be very good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> creating local repo for our commits

This would yet be a good approach, if you install [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/): that system (gerrit) would manage those code-review repos, before allowing to push to the actual blessed repo.

See more in this [Gerrit intro page](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15.3/intro-how-gerrit-works.html):

[image: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9/images/intro-quick-central-gerrit.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Private Code Repositories (as there are many free too) and use their features of generating pull request .

Your team would generate a pull request for you, in case of no issues found in code after reviewing), you would close that pull request and the piece of code gets merged to the branch which was specified while generating pull request.

Have a look at :
https://bitbucket.org/            (Free private Repo)

http://www.github.com/            (Free as public / Paid as private)

Answer (score 1):

Code review systems usually utilize the developer’s discipline to follow a specific workflow. So you don’t actually need a huge code review tool like Gerrit to make it work.

If you set up an intermediary repository and educate your developers to push all changes there (instead of the “blessed” final repository), then you can simply perform code review in that repository and push the changes from there as soon as they seem ready.

This is similar to how code review works on GitHub: You are expected to push your changes to separate branches for which you then create a pull request. The pull request is then used to discuss the changes and review the code. If everything is fine, the branch can be merged into the main development line. All in a single repository.

So you don’t really need a complex system, as long as your developers don’t just push unreviewed code into the final repository.