# Hide git branches from other developers

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online with GIT.
I have 2 branches in local and remote repository say branch1 and branch2.
We are a team of developers and an admin.

As an admin I should see branch1 and branch2 in Visual Studio.
But developer should only see branch2.

Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio Online ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to restrict Git branch access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781240/a-way-to-restrict-git-branch-access)

Answer (score 0):

Your developers need to fork your main repository and use something like Pull Requests to manage the workflow. Here's how GitHub does it: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

This way you can have just `master` in your repository, where only admin can commit/push. Each developer will have his own copy of master (and any other branch).