# Github: Protect a branch but let service accounts push to it

Tags: github

I have a personal website on GitHub Pages. When I merge into develop, my CI is set up to check out master, reset --hard to develop, build the website, and force push to GitHub.

Is there a way I can protect master from being pushed to by anyone else than my CI's service account, so that the only way to update my website is by pushing a verified build to develop?

Since I don't have an organization account, I can't restrict to a particular user using the feature described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39906911/3099140).

Comment: Yes. Branch restrictions as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39906911/1375964

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A way to restrict Git branch access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781240/a-way-to-restrict-git-branch-access)