# Git - How to make subset branches using submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to find ways to configure Git repository for a project on which two groups work.

Each of the two groups should have access authorities as follows.

- Group 1: accessible to both of '/src/dir_public' and '/src/dir_private'
- Group 2: accessible only to '/src/dir_public'

After googling to find out answers, I thought "git-submodule" might be one of the solutions at first.

But after a quick test, I found that it is not I really want.

I thought that submodules would not be tracked from so-called "superproject", but they were.

In other words, I'd like to merge changes in 'src/dir_public' which can be commited by both groups, but I don't want Group2 to know about "src/dir_private".

Would it be possible to configure Git repository as follows?

- Directories visible on "master" branch (group1)

  - src/dir_public (repo_public)
  - src/dir_private (repo_private)
- Directories visible on "private" branch (group1)

  - src/dir_public (repo_public)
  - src/dir_private (repo_private)
- Directories visible on "public" branch (shared with group2)

  - src/dir_public (repo_public)

I'd like to manage/sync-up codes in the following ways

- Merge "public" branch into "master" branch: any update on "public" branch should be merged into "master" branch
- Merge "private" branch into "master" branch: any update on "private" branch should be merged into "master" branch
- Merge "master" branch into "public" branch: **This will work but I don't want dir_private to be visible on "public" branch.**

Lastly, I'm adding what I tested.

```
$ mkdir ~/superproject
$ cd ~/superproject
$ git init
$ mkdir src; mkdir dir_public;
$ cd src/dir_public
$ echo public code > public.c
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "Added the public file."
[master (root-commit) 9b11e8c] Added the public file.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 src/dir_public/public.c

$ mkdir ~/dir_private
$ cd ~/dir_private
$ git init
$ echo private code > private.c
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "Added the private file."
[master (root-commit) 9d34bb2] Added the private file.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dir_private/private.c

$ cd ~/superproject/src
$ git submodule add ~/dir_private/
Cloning into '~/superproject/src/dir_private'...
done.
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   ../.gitmodules
    new file:   dir_private
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer: [A way to restrict Git branch access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781240/a-way-to-restrict-git-branch-access)

What you want to do is fork the repo so you have your own. You can make whatever branches you want. When you're ready to merge with master (or whatever branch everyone is using) you can push. No one will see your branches during your development time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I think my question was somewhat ambiguous, so I edited my question.