# Restrict Git Push/Pull

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to restrict git access from outside my office? For deployment on the server, I am using git cloud. I don't want to give code ( push/pull) access to deployment guy for their home.

Please let me know if there is any way we can restrict.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can restrict based on IP address but, you could implement hooks to restrict writing to a branch. More information here: [How to write a git hook to restrict writing to branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114417/how-to-write-a-git-hook-to-restrict-writing-to-branch)

If you're really interested in using this feature, you can switch to Bitbucket. More information is here: [IP Whitelisting on Bitbucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2017/02/28/big-strides-cloud-security-ip-whitelisting-required-2-step-verification-bitbucket/)

Comment: Can we use any other tool or repo system ?

Comment: Well, if you're really interested in this feature, you can try Bitbucket. I believe they have this feature. Here's more info: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2017/02/28/big-strides-cloud-security-ip-whitelisting-required-2-step-verification-bitbucket/

Comment: @user831413 was that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can get some help from [here](https://github.com/10up/restricted-site-access) about this issue. thie main idea behind this is "Limit access to visitors who are logged in or allowed by IP addresses. Includes many options for handling blocked visitors".